Meaning of ならなくなった in this sentence
From Shirabe Jisho's example sentence

係長が急に辞めてしまったので、私がその穴を埋めなければならなくなった。

While I understand that 穴を埋めなければ means "if we do not fill the hole" - so the conditional form of the verb - I cannot seem to understand what this ならなくなった is being attached to. My guess would be that it is some form of the verb なる ("to become").

It's a combination of ～なければならない and ～なった.

～なければならない essentially means "must". See: Origin of ~なければ ならない
～なった at the end indicates the progression of a situation. "became", "ended up with a situation where ～", "found myself", etc. It takes the continuous form (ku-form) of ない.

Or you can understand the sentence incrementally like this:

埋めなければ
If I don't fill
埋めなければならない
If I don't fill, it's no good
→ It's necessary to fill
埋めなければならなくなった
I ended up with a situation where it's no good if I don't fill
→ It became necessary to fill

